# Why does Django's time filter not pickup the TIME_FORMAT by default?

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

Using `{{today|time:"TIME_FORMAT"}}` correctly localises times when I switch languages in my Django 1.2.3 project. E.g. for English I see `"12:19 a.m."` and when I switch to German it changes to `"12:19:25"`.

As far as I can tell from looking at the docs and code ([`defaultfilters.py`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L702) and [`formats.py`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/utils/formats.py#L59)) just using `{{today:time}}` should do the same thing and default to `TIME_FORMAT` but this isn't working and it always uses the default English format.

Is there a way to avoid having to edit all my templates and change them to `{{today|time:"TIME_FORMAT"}}`?

The same thing happens with the `date` filter and `DATE_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Ned Batchelder, as per option 2., I've added the following to my custom template tags file:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date as defaultfilters_date, time as defaultfilters_time

# FORCE {{...|date}} to be equivalent to {{...|date:"DATE_FORMAT"}} so it localizes properly, ditto for time and TIME_FORMAT

@register.filter(name="date")
def date_localized(val, arg=None):
    return defaultfilters_date(val, arg or "DATE_FORMAT")

@register.filter(name="time")
def time_localized(val, arg=None):
    return defaultfilters_time(val, arg or "TIME_FORMAT")
```

Answer (score 3):

The docs say (emphasis mine):

> When used without a format string:
>
> ```
>  {{ value|time }}
> ```
>
> ...the formatting string defined in the TIME_FORMAT setting will be used, **without applying any localization**.

You have two options:

1. Edit all your templates to make the change, or
2. Create a new filter of your own that does it the way you want.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I didn't see that bit of the docs. Still (assuming you're looking at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#time) it also says:
"Note that the predefined format is locale- dependant." and at the very bottom "Changed in Django 1.2: Predefined formats can now be influenced by the current locale."
So, it sounds like they should be able to be "influenced"...